# grep on Windows 7 Invalid Argument

Tags: windows-7, grep, gnuwin32

I am using grep from [Gnuwin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) on Windows.

Doing:

```
grep -r INSERT *.sql
```

Yields:

```
grep: *.sql: Invalid argument
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Have you updated gnuwin32? Command appears to work correctly for me. There was an older bug that had this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Grep manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html):

`-r` with grep is recursive directory searching, so to use it you specify the starting directory, not a file mask.

e.g.:

`grep -r INSERT .` would look at all files for INSERT, starting at the current directory (`.`) and recursively working its way through the sub-folders.

To specify recursive folder checking *and* specify a file wildcard to limit searches, you can use the `--include` option:

`grep -r --include "*.sql" INSERT .`

Similar question/info over on StackOverflow: [How do I grep recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987926/how-do-i-grep-recursively)

Comment: I think I need to update my grep.  I have no --include option! But this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no *.sql file.

Comment: While that in fact is true, adding -r yields the same error.

Comment: @Mike bash expands `*.sql` to all files/ directories matching this pattern. Since nothing matches, you get the error. `-r` doesn't have anything to do with this

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  There are no files with an extension of .sql in the folder where I ran the command.  There are subfolders and they _do_ in fact have files with .sql as the extension.  Shouldn't the `-r` help then?

Comment: [TECHIE007](http://superuser.com/users/23133/%c6%ac%e1%b4%87c%ca%9c%ce%b9%e1%b4%87007) has a nice answer to this. Completely unrelated to your question, perhaps for fun, or for comparison, I'd like just to add the non-Gnuwin32 solution that likely does the same thing: `@for /f  %i in ('dir /s/b *.sql') do @(type %i | find "INSERT" > nul && if errorlevel 0 echo %i)`.

Answer (score 1):

`grep` is a great tool with some interesting parameters. However, as its name says (**g**lobally search a **r**egular **e**xpression and **p**rint) it is meant for matching things. If what you want is to find files, use `find`.

In this case, it looks like you want to look for the text `INSERT` within files that are in this tree.

For this, you need to do something like:

```
find -name "*.sql" grep -h INSERT {} \;
```

`find -name "*.sql"` will find all these files and then `grep -h` will print those having the text `INSERT` in them.

---

**Why wasn't your approach working?**

Because by saying `grep -r ... *.sql`, bash tries to expand that `*.sql` before performing the command. But nothing matches `*.sql` in your directory, so it cannot work.

You can use the `--include` parameter with a regexp, but -in my experience- it is quite fragile.